# Regex match on any two characters where the two characters start with anything but a backslash and then a space

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, regex-negation

I have a string sample like this: `us-west,AAA 4589235i date=Wed\\ Dec\\ 12\\ 02:27:22\\ UTC\\ 2018`

I want to split it up by the spaces...*except for the spaces preceded by '\'*.  There could be any variation of strings like this and spaces could be preceded by a `"` or a `$` or `&`.  I just want to avoid the the `\`s because this is data being sent with escapes I want to ignore.

How can I match on *exactly* `<any character except '\'>\s`?

Comment: `[^\\]\s` should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, maybe you're trying to do:

```
import re

string = '''us-west,AAA 4589235i date=Wed\\\\ Dec\\\\ 12\\\\ 02:27:22\\\\ UTC\\\\ 2018'''

expression = r'(?<!\\\\)\s'

print(re.split(expression, string))
```

#### Output

```
['us-west,AAA', '4589235i', 'date=Wed\\\\ Dec\\\\ 12\\\\ 02:27:22\\\\ UTC\\\\ 2018']
```

---

If you wish to simplify/update/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/PgYRxc/1/). You can watch the matching steps or modify them in [this debugger link](https://regex101.com/r/PgYRxc/1/debugger), if you'd be interested. The debugger demonstrates that how [a RegEx engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines) might step by step consume some sample input strings and would perform the matching process.

---

Comment: You win!  Thanks @Emma!